# How to calculate the sum of average of subdocuments that match a given criteria?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure:

```
[
    {
        series_id: 0,
        books: [
            {
                book_id: 0,
                scores: [
                    {
                        critic_id: 0,
                        score : 7.5
                    },
                    {
                        critic_id: 1,
                        score : 8.5
                    },
                    {
                        critic_id: 2,
                        score : 2.5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                book_id: 1,
                scores: [
                    {
                        critic_id: 0,
                        score : 5.5
                    },
                    {
                        critic_id: 1,
                        score : 7.5
                    },
                    {
                        critic_id: 2,
                        score : 9.5
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Now, I want to find the series that have the highest summed score for the average score per book given a list of critic ids (preferably ordered).

So, for example, I want to find the series that score highest for critics [0,2]. This should return:

```
[
    {
        series_id: 0,
        score: 12.5 
    },
    ...
]
```

or simply an ordered list of series ids:

```
[ 0, ... ]
```

Because the average foor book_0 for critics 0 and 2 is 5, and the average for book_1 for critics 0 and 2 is 7.5. Summed this is 12.5

For now I am stuck at:

```
return list(db['series']).find(sort=[("series.books.scores", 1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in version 3.2, the `$avg` accumulator expressions, previously only available in the `$group` stage, are now also available in the `$project` stage we can then take advantage of that to shorten our previous pipeline.

To do that you `$project` your documents after the `$redact` stage and using the `$avg` operator in our projection we can return the average of the array of score returned by [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) then use the `$group` to return the expected result.

```
db.series.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
        'books.scores.critic_id': { '$in': [ 0,2 ] }
    }},
    { '$unwind': '$books' }, 
    { '$project': { 
        'series_id': 1, 
        'book_id': '$books.book_id', 
        'scores': '$books.scores'
    }},
    { '$redact': {
        '$cond': [
            { '$or': [
                { '$eq': [ '$critic_id', 0 ] }, 
                { '$eq': [ '$critic_id', 2 ] },
                { '$not': '$critic_id' }
            ]}, 
            '$$DESCEND', '$$PRUNE'
        ]
    }}, 
    { '$project': { 
        'series_id': 1, 
        'score': {
            '$avg': { 
                '$map': { 
                    'input': '$scores', 
                    'as': 'score', 
                    'in': '$$score.score'
                }
            }
        }
    }}, 
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$_id', 
        'series_id': { '$first': '$series_id' }, 
        'score': { '$sum': '$score' }
    }}
])
```

Which yields:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56543c98571635184da33953"), "series_id" : 0, "score" : 12.5 }
```

---

Prior to MongoDB 3.2 you will need to denormalize the "books" array then `$project` our documents. From there we can then use the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) to return reduce the size of documents that will be processed at the next stage. Then comes the `$unwind` and `$group` stages.

```
db.series.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 
        'books.scores.critic_id': { '$in': [ 0, 2 ] }
    }},
    { '$unwind': '$books' }, 
    { '$project': { 
        'series_id': 1, 
        'book_id': '$books.book_id', 
        'scores': '$books.scores'
    }},
    { '$redact': {
        '$cond': [
            { '$or': [
                { '$eq': [ '$critic_id', 0 ] }, 
                { '$eq': [ '$critic_id', 2 ] }, 
                { '$not': '$critic_id' } 
            ]}, 
            '$$DESCEND', '$$PRUNE'
        ]
    }}, 
    { '$unwind': '$scores' },
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$book_id', 
        'series_id': { '$first': '$series_id' }, 
        'avgScores': { '$avg': '$scores.score' }
    }},
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$series_id', 
        'score': { '$sum': '$avgScores' }
    }} 
])
```

Which yields:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "score" : 12.5 }
```

---

Another way do this is to first filter out documents that 'critic_id' not [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) `[0, 2]` using the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator. Next in our pipeline is the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) stages to denormalize both "books" and "scores" arrays. From there you need two [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stages. The first one to calculate the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) of "score" and the second to return [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) of those averages.

```
db.series.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
        'books.scores.critic_id': { '$in': [ 0,2 ] }
    }}, 
    { '$unwind': '$books' }, 
    { '$unwind': '$books.scores' },
    { '$match': { 
        'books.scores.critic_id': { '$in': [ 0, 2 ] }
    }}, 
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$books.book_id',
        'series_id': { '$first': '$series_id' }, 
        'total': { '$avg': '$books.scores.score' }
    }}, 
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$series_id', 
        'score': { '$sum': '$total' }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "score" : 12.5 }
```

You can always add an optional [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage to the end of the pipeline like this:

```
{ '$project': { 
    'series_id': '$_id', 
    'score': 1, 
    '_id': 0
}}
```

To return this:

```
{ "score" : 12.5, "series_id" : 0 }
```

But this will cause a drop of performance.

**It worth noting that PyMongo returns a cursor so you will need to loop over the cursor and print the result.**